# How do I share a link to a Firebase Crashlytics report?

Tags: firebase, crashlytics

Has anyone figured out how to get a permalink to a Firebase Crashlytics issue? I'd like to paste an issue link in our bug tracker. The only way I know right now is the copy the address bar, but the link looks like this:

https:/​/console.firebase.google.com/u/1/project/foo-apps/crashlytics/app/ios:com.foo.bar/issues/1234abcd?time=last-thirty-days&sessionId=abcd1234

This is less than ideal: "u/1" refers to a logged-in Google account that only makes sense in my browser. There is also a session ID and search filter; that's easy enough to delete, but it's annoying.

Comment: Fabric.io doesn't have a share button, but at least this is what the same report looks like in the address bar: https:-slash-slash-fabric.io/scorevision/mac/apps/com.foo.bar/issues/1234abcd?time=last-thirty-days No user-specific information.

Comment: "less than ideal" is putting it lightly.  In order to be a viable crash reporting system, we need to be able to track back from project management software through to crash reports.  To me, having only a broken means for doing so means Firebase Crashlytics fails at a most basic function of crash management.

Comment: I’ve submitted a feature request: https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/features. I might suggest that anyone who needs this feature consider doing the same. I agree that this is a curious omission...

Comment: I cannot believe that the URL contains "u/1". This is making it impossible to pass around the issue link amongst the team.  Extremely frustrating.